# If a product has a special price add a new category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, special-price

I'm trying to create a cron job that checks if a product has a special price and if it does it adds it to the sale category as well as the one it is currently in.

```
$category_id = 9;
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->addTaxPercents();
$productposted = array();
foreach ($collection as $product){
    if(($product->getFinalPrice() < $product->getPrice()) && ($_product->getData('sale_expempt')==1)) {
        $productposted[$product->getId()]  = 9;
    }
}
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$category->setPostedProducts($productposted);
$category->save();
```

Comment: A better way would be to create a new category and make a template check on the desired cat. Like "If Cat == 3, and price !== normal price: do something. That *might* be quicker. Just an idea. I know your question is something else.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Yeah my sale category id is 9, so if a product has a special price I need to move it to that one.

Comment: If it helps this is what I have so far to check if there is a special price:

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
 $sale_categoryid = 9;

    if ($product->getFinalPrice() < $product->getPrice())  {

        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below solution

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()   
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents() ;
 $productposted = array();
 foreach ($collection as $product){
   if($product->getFinalPrice() < $product->getPrice()){
      $productposted[$product->getId()]  = 1; //or your sort order
   }
}
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);//your category id
$category->setPostedProducts($productposted);
$category->save();
```

Comment: I get this straight away:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on null in Path/to/site/app/mage.php:463 Stack trace: #0 path/to/site/cronjobs/sale_cron.php(22): Mage::getModel('catalog/product') #1 {main} thrown in /path/to/site/app/mage.php on line 463

Comment: could you provide whole code you have tried, also check updated code

Comment: I've updated it in the question, thank you

Comment: updated with your code now

Comment: so you have productId so you want to check current product ??

Comment: I want to check for all products if the have a special price then they get added to another category

Comment: remove `$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);`  this line

Comment: I have done, i'm still getting the same error

Comment: @TomBeachell check updated code

Comment: If this still errors, post us your whole code into your question. Maybe there's a typo somewhere.

Comment: I was missing Mage::app() it is working now

Comment: @TomBeachell if this answer help you then mark as accepted, so other users take benifit from this

Comment: @TomBeachell you are  welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to do something similar with Magento 2 but have just created a page for Special Offers and that filters the product collection for products with a special price. Something along these lines in Magento 1:
http://inchoo.net/magento/more-flexible-approach-for-listing-out-products-on-sale-in-magento/
I know it's not quite what you are looking for but it you want to achieve a special offers page this is the way i would go about it.